# How to install xindy on Ubuntu

Tags: installing, ubuntu, xindy

How can I install xindy package to use texindy?

I read this manual [xindy.sourceforge.net/download-binary.html](http://xindy.sourceforge.net/download-binary.html) but i didn't get promised `bin` and `man` subfolders inside `xindy-2.3` but this:
[image]

And I remember well, that few months ago I used texindy without any difficulties, probably then I installed it with some another package.

EDIT: I have installed texlive-full, and i read that xindy should be there. But apparently it is not.

EDIT2:  I ran `tlmgr list` and got

- xindy: A general-purpose index processor
- xindy.alpha-linux: alpha-linux files of xindy
- xindy.amd64-freebsd: amd64-freebsd files of xindy
- ...
- xindy.x86_64-darwin: x86_64-darwin files of xindy
- xindy.x86_64-linux: x86_64-linux files of xindy

Should i add some path for xindy to work to PATH?

EDIT3: searching for texlive gave me

```
./usr/share/texlive
./usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive
./usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/texlive
./var/lib/tex-common/fmtutil-cnf/texlive
./var/lib/tex-common/hyphen-cnf/texlive
./var/lib/tex-common/fontmap-cfg/texlive
```

Comment: You can also use the official Ubuntu repository, which contains many LaTeX packages (although slightly older versions). In this case: `sudo apt install xindy`.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks a lot. You may put it as an answer and i will accept it, if you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many LaTeX packages and related tools are also available in the official Ubuntu repositories and can be installed with `apt`.

The advantage of using this repository is that installing is easy, and issues with paths, dependencies, permissions etc. (such as in the current question) are usually avoided.

The disadvantage is that these repositories do not contain the latest versions, because of the long release cycle of Ubuntu. Therefore, already solved bugs may be there and features may be missing. For normal use however this does not tend to be a problem.

In this case: `sudo apt install xindy`, which is version 2.4-1.3 for 16.04 LTS. Ubuntu Yakkety and Zesty contain xindy 2.5.